# MultiPartEntityBuilder cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java

I  used a newer class to substitute a deprecated one. The class is MultiPartEntityBuilder. When i wrote it in the code, the compiler suggested me to import the following package

```
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
```

I have imported it. But the compiler cannot still find it, giving me the error on the title

```
MultiPartEntityBuilder cannot be resolved to a type
```

So, it sounds quite strange to me. I've already succesfully imported similar packages

```
    import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.ContentBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
```

Does it mean i have an old version which doesn't define any class named MultiPartEntityBuilder ?
How does the compiler know that i should import that class, part of that package, if he got an old version of that package?

Please note that

```
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
```

is market as an error.

Answer (score 10):

Upload Apache HttpClient Mime 4.3.1 jar file http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime/4.3.1

Comment: For those as bad at java and java build tools as I am - this link includes the copy-past for 
 xml for pom file

Answer (score 0):

It means that org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder isn't accessible during compilation time. You should add it to your project somehow depends on your build tool.

Comment: How? I really have no idea, i downloaded the full .zip from here https://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi (4.3.6.zip) and the class reference http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntityBuilder.html tells it's included in 4.3 ...

Comment: yeah, that's why you see this Exception, you have specified classpath for your project , but didn't add it to your project. I don't know which build tool you are using, but as a way I think you can just put jar in your lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a spelling error, you had MultiPartEntityBuilder instead of MultipartEntityBuilder.  The "P" shouldn't be capitalised.